# How to create image Gallery with Zooming in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, image, zooming, scrollview

When we work with single image it works fine but when we add multiple images in ScrollView then it   zooms only on the first image.

This code works with single image but how to implement this method for multiple images.

```
- (UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return imageview;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an UIView object and put all the images onto it. And tell the delegate that this UIView is the view should be zoomed.